# SQL query for finding matched result based on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables.

## 1. items

```
id    user_id   image 
1       12        -
```

## 2. item_details

```
id     item_id      category_field_id       value               is_description
1         1               11                 honda                  0
2         1               12                 xblade                 0  
3         1               13                 X123                   0   
4         1               14                 its a very good bike   1
```

These tables used to store item details of dynamic forms based on category_field_id. so here what i need is that

i need all items list based on exact match of user search

```sql
where (category_field_id = 11 AND value = honda)
AND   (category_field_id = 12 AND value = xblade)
AND   (category_field_id = 13 AND value = X123)
AND   (category_field_id = 14 AND value LIKE search_string_from_website);
```

except description field all fileds match and description field in like clause.
i have tried but i can't get any proper solution. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to find items where all four of the conditions are true *on separate rows*.  That suggests aggregation:

```
select item_id
from item_details
group by item_id
having sum(category_field_id = 11 AND value = 'honda') > 0 and
       sum(category_field_id = 12 AND value = 'xblade') > 0 and
       sum(category_field_id = 13 AND value = 'X123') > 0 and
       sum(category_field_id = 14 AND value LIKE 'search_string_from_website') > 0 ;
```